# Format string time to short time format

Tags: c#, time

I have a collection of data in my database, time and description, choose String as data type of my time, my question is how can I format my time data to this format "HH:MM AM/PM"

The time is "4:45 PM", I want to format this into this format "04:45 PM" in C# but I do not know how can I format that.

here is my code:

```
var str = touritinerary.Model.Time; //"4:45 PM"
var timePattern = "h:mm";
DateTime finalizeTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out finalizeTime))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Time: {1:hh:mm }", finalizeTime);
}
```

I want 4:45 PM formatted into 04:45 PM

Comment: You know that you can store `time` directly in the DB, at least in SQL Server 2008 and later. You don't need to store it as a string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx The same is true for MySQL and, I suspect but haven't checked, Oracle.

Comment: condition is false, my string str didn't convert.

Comment: my statement ignore the condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close.

- Use `0` instead of `1`, since `finalizeTime` is the first (and only) argument to `WriteLine`.
- Include `tt` to display `PM`.

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Time: {0:hh:mm tt }", finalizeTime);
```

Output:

`Time: 04:45 PM`

Comment: but my condition (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out finalizeTime) doesn't work

Comment: @A.J You can mark amswers as accepted, this let's others know what solved the problem for you and Grant gets some cool Internet points. Click the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Grant Winney, thanks again, i forgot to change my time pattern, my time pattern is wrong so that my statement didn't execute my console.writeLine, here is my code  var timePattern = "h:mm tt";

Answer (score 4):

You **read the documentation**:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Try

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") ;
```

Answer (score -3):

You will find [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) incredibly useful, it has all the DateTime formatting info you need from MSDN.

```
Console.WriteLine("Time: {0: hh:mm tt}", finalizeTime);
```